# Excel - How to extend Data entry to include whole line

Tags: excel

I have data which is added onto a Data file (sheet 2). This data contains 3 cells that are transferred to the main database (sheet 1) using `='Staff Data'!` code in each cell. The data which is sorted on sheet 2 alphabetically, is also shown on sheet 1 alphabetically. There is also information on sheet 1 that is linked to the names shown on the first 3 lines.

[image: Before adding a name]

My problem is when I add a new name to sheet 2, it gets placed alphabetically into the list. When this is transferred to sheet 1 using the formula `='Staff Data'!`, the list has increased by a line where the new name has been added. Unfortunately the rest of the row doesn't adjust to the new name entry. For example, columns 1 to 3 has 150 rows of names. Columns 4 to 20 also have 150 rows of information. If I add a new name into Sheet 2, this increases the number of rows to 151, but the new name has actually been placed at, say, row 89. On sheet 1 at row 89 the new name appears on rows 1 to 3, but rows 4 to 20 still only has 150 rows, and the information is now not in line with the names in lines 1 to 3 as they were before the new name was added.

[image: After new name added]

Is there something I can add to the formula in the cells of columns 1 to 3 that will tell Excel to insert the whole row, rather than just the first 3 columns? Or is this something that can only be achieved using VBA?

Comment: It's hard to understand your seituation exactly, could you provide some example data or screenshots of the relevant parts?

Comment: Why can't you extend the range that needs sorted on columns A:C? This question could do with some additional information to make it a [mcve].

Comment: Sorry I didn't make myself clearer. I have a main database (sheet 1) that receives input from other sheets that users enter data on (Sheets 2 & 3). On sheet 2 Users enter Names, location, and Unique reference numbers on a form. The information from this form is then transferred to sheet 1 using the formula ```=Sheet 1!```. What happens is this information is also sorted Alphabetically, so the information  could be inserted anywhere in the list, so moving the subsequent names one line down.

Comment: Sheet 3 has information entered by users, and dependent on the information this is transferred to sheet 1 along the cells from D to AK via VBA code. This information is supposed to be tied to the unique reference number in cell C. Trouble is the rest of the line D to AK doesn't move down when information gets inserted into cells A to C. I am not sure how to show a screenshot of what I am trying to describe here. If you can describe how I can do this, I will certainly supply a screenshot if this helps.

Comment: Sorry, the formula should say ```=Sheet 2!```

Comment: Kindly edit the question to include the new/extra info.. ( :

Comment: I have amended and added some images to try and make the original question clearer.

Comment: "Columns 4 to 20 also have 150 rows of information" <- May I know.. is these data entered manually.. or there is a formula/link to sheet 2 ?

Comment: The information is added automatically from another sheet (sheet 3) where the unique number in column C matches, this makes the date appear in column L on the correct line. Columns M & N have formulas that feed off the information in column L. I am using VBA to transfer the information from Sheet 3 into the main sheet shown. I can supply the VBA code if you wish?